# How to align lines below each other

Tags: latex

In the test file I am creating I try to have the following format in the pdf:

```
    Instructor1: name
    Instructor2: name
    (Company Name)
```

but when I run the below latex code I get the following:

```
    Instructor1: name
Instructor2: name (Company Name)
```

**latex**:

```
\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
Instructor1: name
\begin{normalsize}
\hfill \break \hspace{130pt} Instructor2: name.
(Company Name)
\end{normalsize}
\end{normalsize}
```

**update**

**latex**:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {F:/ArbeitOrdner2015/reports/imagesLatex/} }
\author{Anan}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

 \hspace{140pt}
 \includegraphics{rsz_fh_logo}
\section*{\hspace{120pt}University name}
\vspace{10pt}
\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
University Name
\end{normalsize}
\vspace{10pt}
\section*{\hspace{150pt}\textbf{Master Thesis}}
Presented at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx To Complete The XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\vspace{10pt}
\section*{\hspace{100pt} Speed Limit warning System}

\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
submitted by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\end{normalsize}

\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
Matriculation Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\end{normalsize}

\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
Major of Study: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.
\end{normalsize}

\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
Specialization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.
\end{normalsize}

\hspace{130pt}\begin{normalsize}
Instructor1: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\begin{normalsize}
\hfill \break \hspace{130pt} Instructor2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
(Company name)
\end{normalsize}
\end{normalsize}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: What is, precisely, the effect you want to achieve? Instructor1: name, Instructor2: name, (Company Name) aligned and indented by 130pt? Why all of that nesting of normalsizes??

Comment: @MattAllegro no instructor1 and instructor 2 are not exactly alligned under each other please see the second code snippt posted in my question above

Comment: Get rid of all of those normalsizes and manually specified hspaces...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is the `tabbing` environment in Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent These are my instructors intendented, using third column (30+30=60pt indent)
 \begin{tabbing}
    \hspace{30pt}\=\hspace{30pt}\=\kill
    \>  \> Instructor 1: John Doe \\ 
    \>  \> Instructor 2: Jane Doe  \\
    \>  \> Doe and Doe Inc.
\end{tabbing}
\noindent Or lets tab them all out 130pt at once, using only two columns:
\begin{tabbing}
        \hspace{130pt}\=\kill
        \> Instructor 1: John Doe \\ 
        \> Instructor 2: Jane Doe  \\
        \> Doe and Doe Inc.
    \end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

You can control tab width via the header of tabbing environment, and each new tab is added using `\>`.

Answer (score 0):

A *poor man's* solution:

```latex
\hspace{130pt}\begin{minipage}{300pt}
submitted by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx\\
Matriculation Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx\\
Major of Study: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.\\
Specialization: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx.\\
Instructor1: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx

\vspace{1em}

Instructor2: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx\\
(Company name)
\end{minipage}
```

This should just make you wonder if specifying the `hspace` or indentation only once would be better.